# Application or Object defined error in range.formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set a formula to certain cells. The code for setting the formula in a for loop is like this:

```
For i = 0 To MotorAmount
            Set myCell = Range(Target.Address).Offset(i, 1)
            myCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Range(Target.Address);Database!$B$31:$G$131;2;False);0)"
Next i
```

However I get an application or object defined error on the line that starts with myCell.Formula. I hope someone can tell me why the error occurs and how to fix it.

PS: I use semicolons in the formula because my Excel works like that. the 'Database' is the name of another sheet I use.

PS2: The sub is placed in Sheet1 under Microsoft Excel Objects in the VBAProject.

The complete code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim MotorAmount As Integer

Set myRange = Range("A68:A168")
If Not Application.Intersect(myRange, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If Not Range(Target.Address) = "" Then
        MotorAmount = InputBox("How many motors are used in this transport?", "Amount of motors")
        For i = 0 To MotorAmount
            Set myCell = Range(Target.Address).Offset(i, 1)
            myCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Range(Target.Address);Database!$B$31:$G$131;2;False);0)"
        Next i
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula implementation should be:

`myCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & Target.Address & ",Database!$B$31:$G$131,2,False),0)"`

**Note:** In VBA use commas while writing formula, in native it will automatically show the correct argument separator you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put code inside a formula and you should be using commas not semicolons in the formula as VBA is US-centric. I'd suggest using R1C1 references:

```
myCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R" & Target.Row & "C1,Database!R31C2:R131C7,2,False),0)"
```

Comment: Allright, thanks for the feedback. I changed it, but still get the error. Aren't you using code inside a formula with the target.row statement?

Comment: No, because I concatenated the result into the formula string, rather than actually putting the code in the formula. I just noticed you're creating a circular reference as the first cell you put the formula in is the one you are using as a lookup value.